# Credentials for the Xcode Server xcs.couch database

Tags: couchdb, xcode-server

Xcode 9 introduces a new version of the Xcode Server (no longer bundled with with Server.app). The backing couchdb instance for Xcode Server can be accessed through

http://localhost:10355/_utils

In previous versions you were able to examine the documents and even modify if needed. (For instance, I previously did this to artificially inflate an integration number when setting up a bot on a different server. I use the $(XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER) variable for my build numbers.)

Now, the database requires credentials. I know you can find the password in

```
/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/SharedSecrets/XCSDCouchDBSecret
```

But does anyone know the username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more investigation I found my answer...

```
/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Configuration/xcscouch.ini
```

This file contains the basic CouchDB configuration for the Xcode Server. Under the `[admins]` section is a `username=password` list.

The default username for the Xcode Server CouchDB instance is `xcscouchadmin`